# FreeNas 7.x - Create user via SSH

Tags: freebsd, truenas

Hello i'm using FreeNas 7.x

I need to access my webadmin-interface but i can't login with my credentials (that works with SSH). I've SSH Access, is it possibile to create a user (with access to webadmin interface) via SSH? How?

Or is there another possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine you can reset password for your account from console and seems to enable (again) web access for the user.

However i have 2 machines with the same problem and i don't have physical access on one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have physical access to the machine you can reset password for your account from console and seems to enable (again) web access for the user. However i have 2 machines with the same problem and i don't have physical access on one of them